# xembedsniproxy running beserc after boot on Kubuntu 21.04

Tags: kubuntu, ps

Each time I reboot, a process named xembedsniproxy is consuming 60-70% of one of my cores and if I let it continue it goes to 100% leading to system lag.
When I kill the process, the system works without any visible side effects for me.
Is there a way to see what program involkes this process?

PS: It seems that the process only spawns when I plug my laptop into my displaylink dock at work (which I need to do on a daily basis). Interestingly, when I plug my laptop into my (identical) displaylink dock at home, the problem does not arise. The difference between the two setups are, that at work my dock is connected to two external monitors and a mechanical keyboard by razer. At home I have only one external monitor and a cheap membrane keyboard.

ps: As expected running a kde wayland session solves the problem.

PS: After updating to 22.10 the problem reappeared. I guess it has to do with the interplay between the displaylink driver and the new kernel.

Comment: It has been discussed here https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=289&t=168880 and here https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/511359-Too-many-xembeds

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you. I do not have a custom theme, so i do not fully understand what would cause this in my case.